# How to skip stuff in a file using fscanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am learning C file operations and I have a specific problem where I need to store alphabets (A-Z, a-z) as a string read from a file. So, if I have `abcd&*dvcd` then `abcd` is a string and `dvcd` is a string.

Essentially I have two problems:

1. I don't know the size of the string to store before hand.
2. I need to skip non-alphabetic characters

I thought I would solve both by using fscanf format string. This is my thought. I need to somehow skip using `fscanf` format string to find my position in file. Then, I could subtract from the saved beginning position to find the string I need to `malloc`. Then, I `malloc` the string of specific length, and then, I could go back to the saved position and actually read it.

However, I have no idea how to tell `fscanf` to not store the scanned string?

Or if there is another method that allows to skip non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: You should look hard at the POSIX documentation on [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html)
and see whether that is available to you — features such as the `m` modifier for use in `%ms` help a lot.  You should look at 'scan sets' (`%[…]`) and `*` to suppress assignment.  Even more, you should review the use of standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) in conjunction with `sscanf()`.  It is typically easier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh. You mean store the string from the file in memory? I don't think that is feasible because I will be using the program with very very large text files...

Comment: Where else are you planning to store it?  It needn't use very much more memory than what you're planning to do — perhaps 32 bytes per string more, if you're unlucky.  You can delete strings after you read and process each line — otherwise, you leak memory.

Comment: Using the fgets, how would I know what the string length is? It could be a string spanning multiple lines

Comment: per the question statement, the string could not span multiple lines because the newline is not in the set a...z nor A...Z

Comment: do you plan on separating strings by any `white space`, like the space char or a tab char, etc.  The question statement seems to say that `white space` would cause a string separation.    Therefore, suggest using readline() or similar function as that would perform the memory allocation for you, so you do not need to worry about the length of a string.  After the file input for a line is completed,  iterate through the read-in data, char by char extracting each successive string

Comment: What are you doing with the strings - are you reading the whole file into memory, or calling a function each time a string is read, or what? (I ask because this will help with writing a code sample to do the reading)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format specifier like "%[a-zA-Z]" in format specifier in fscanf.
Like the below example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char a[10];
        fscanf(stdin, "%[a-zA-Z]", a);
        printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

In this example it reads the alphabets only in the stdin. It skips the non alphabet characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since @suresh' answer is [not working for me](http://ideone.com/N7tAf4) (the output should be `asd gddf` and not `asd asd`), I have written another version, which is not as short but works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch;
    while(scanf("%1c", &ch) == 1) { //while we have characters to read
        if(isalpha(ch)) { // if the next one is alphanumeric
            ungetc(ch, stdin); // we put it back
            char str[101];
            scanf("%100[a-zA-Z]", str); // to read the whole string (including that char)
            printf("found string %s\n", str);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/1UvF0n) is a working ideone example. I use stdin for this one, but you can easily adapt it to use another file you have open. The format specifier I used for `scanf` (`%100[a-zA-Z]]`) means that it should read at most 100 characters (the size of str) containing only lowercase or uppercase letters. `%1c` means a single character, and `unget` puts the character back into the buffer to avoid skipping it if it's not a symbol.

Edit: as @m-m pointed out, the use of `-` inside the square brackets is not standard and may not be available in some implementations. If it is not available for you, you can always use `%100[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.

Comment: Using `-` inside `%[` is implementation-defined ; some standard libraries might not support the behaviour you are relying on