# Can I set non-alphabetic characters as a delimeter in c when using fscanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf, delimiter

I'm trying to read strings from a file using

```
while(fscanf(fd, "%s ", word) != EOF) {}
```

Where fd is the file and word is where I'm storing the string. 
However, this effectively uses the whitespace as the delimeter. Currently, if I have a file that reads "this% is, the4 str%ng" it would result in strings "this%", "is,", "the4", and "str%ng". I need it to be "this" "is" "the" "str" "ng". Is it possible to do this with fscanf, or is there something else I need to use?

I saw some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893852/how-to-ignore-non-alphabetic-characters-in-c-when-read-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227218/how-to-skip-stuff-in-a-file-using-fscanf) but they didn't seem to help me out.

Comment: fscanf() returns the number of items scanned. How can that ever be EOF?

Comment: From the man page *"The value EOF is returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion"*. But it *is* better to compare the return value to the number of expected conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those answers show the use of the `"%[]` format specifier. As an example suppose you have this to get two strings from the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char s1[100] = "", s2[100] = "";
    int res;

    res = scanf("%99[^%]%%%99[^%]%%", s1, s2);
    printf("%d %s %s\n", res, s1, s2);
}
```

The first `%` starts the each format spec, the `^%` tells `scanf` to stop at `%`, and the next "escaped" double `%` tells scanf to read the `%` that stopped the scan. It then repeats for the second string, so the format spec for one string is `%99[^%]%%` .

To make the format look simpler, suppose the delimiter is not `%` but `#`, then the code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char s1[100] = "", s2[100] = "";
    int res;

    res = scanf("%99[^#]#%99[^#]#", s1, s2);
    printf("%d %s %s\n", res, s1, s2);
}
```

The function `fscanf` is similar.

---

**EDIT**

This answer does not handle "unknown" delimiters, so I modified the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char s1[100] = "";
    while(scanf("%99[^!£$%&*()_-+={};:'@#~,.<>/?0123456789]", s1) == 1) {
        getchar();                      // remove the delimiter
        printf("%s\n", s1);
    }
}
```

Note I have not included characters `^` or `"` or `[` or `]` as delimiters.

Comment: It was a great example, but I wondered why I have never saw `[` format specification. Check and noticed that it seems this is a POSIX specified delimiter. So it may not work in windows (I didn't see it in MSDN). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx

Comment: @Afshin I improved the answer, and this does work with MSVC.

Comment: @Afshin `"%[scan_set]"`  is well defined in the standard C library.  If the compiler used in windows is compliant, it works there too.  It is not an an OS issue but a compiler/library one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a specific delimiter (it seems to be your case), you need to parse each file line manually. You can read each line with `fgets()`, then parse manually(for example ignore every non-alphabetic chars).

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, the skill of writing char-handling code has been lost.  Char arrays can only be handled by stringing together libray calls:)